# Making a generic method to fit all classes... is that possible?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have N classes of core data entities. Every class has properties slightly different.

I am populating all entities with data from a `CSV` file. The first line of the file contains the header, that may be like this:

```
code1,code2,code3,code4,ref1,ref2
```

or may be like this

```
code1,code2,code3,ref1
```

or in other words, different number of "code" and different number of "ref"

The elements of this header have the exact name of the properties of the core data entity it represents and entity has the same name of the file.

Example:

1. file name is `Cars.csv`
2. `Cars.csv` header is `code1,code2,code3,ref1`
3. Entity name is `Cars`
4. `Cars` entity has properties code1, code2, code3 and ref.

Said that, this is what I want to do.

I have a method that reads a csv file, line by line, and will be used to populate the database. The method so far is like this:

```
- (void) populateDatabaseEntityFromFile:(NSString *)fileName {


  // all lines of the file are stored on array
  NSArray* allLines = [self readAllLinesOfFile:fileName];

  //get the header
  NSString *firstLine = [linhas objectAtIndex:0];
  NSArray *header = [firstLine componentsSeparatedByString: @","];


  // iterate over all lines... start with i=1 to ignore the header
  for (int i=1; i<[allLines count]; i++) { 

    NSString *oneLine = [allLines objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *valuesOnLine = [oneLine componentsSeparatedByString: @","];

    // MAGIC COMMAND 1 HERE
    // insert a new object on a core data entity


    // iterate over the values of a line
    for (int i=0; i<[header count]; i++) {

      NSInteger oneValue = [[valuesOnLine objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
      NSString *oneProperty = [header objectAtIndex:i];


      // MAGIC COMMAND 2 HERE, to populate the entity


    }

}
```

what I mean by magic commands 1 and 2 is this:

**MAGIC COMMAND 1**

At this point I need to insert a new object on the entity.

If this was hardwired to a specific entity, I would do this like

```
Entity1 *newObj = [Entity1 insertNewObjectImManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

but I cannot hardwire it to Entity1. I need something generic like:

```
"entity that has the same name as fileName" *newObj = ["entity that has the same name as fileName" insertNewObjectImManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

**MAGIC COMMAND 2**

It is time to populate the database, once the entity is created by the magic command 1, I can do

```
[newObj setValue:@(oneValue) forKey:oneProperty];
```

so, how do I do that magic command 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a managed object "dynamically" (without hardwiring it to a specific
entity), you can do:

```
NSString *entity = @"Car";
NSEntityDescription *desc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entity inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *object = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:desc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

And to set the keys and values dynamically, the following should work:

```
NSArray *header = ...; // The attribute names from your header line
NSArray *valuesOnLine = ...; // The corresponding attribute values 
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:valuesOnLine forKeys: header];
[object setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
```